# Unable to find the program >> in Mac

Tags: unix, find, append

I want to search the program ">>" that is by which you append to a file.

I run the code unsuccessfully in Mac

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep " >> "
```

I get too many results to find the correct app.
The program is not among other teletypes at /bin.

**How can you find the program ">>"?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no program called ">>"  - it's just a part of the shell's syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was looking for a command which reappends TextA to FileA, similarly as >> but to reverse direction in the file. It seems that I need to make a separate program for that.

Comment: Masi, are you thinking something like `cat TextA >> FileA`?

Comment: I mean to have a command which puts TextA to the beginning of FileA.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shell operator, not a program at all.

Read the code for `bash`. Or find a simpler implementation of a Bourne Shell. There must be several on the web. Here is one http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a program, this is a shell construct. Try `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it's just part of the syntax. Like + and - are part of math syntax. If you want to overwrite a file, use a single >, to append use double >>.
It works both ways. So if you want to use a file as input, just use <. Each line of the file will be passed to the command.
command < file.txt